# Kotlin build in ARM

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, apple-m1

I am trying to [build](https://github.com/walt-id/waltid-ssikit/blob/master/build.gradle.kts) on my Mac M1. I am experiencing several problems. When I run the build script I get:

```
* What went wrong:
Unable to calculate the value of the task ':compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'.
> Unable to download a toolchain that matches these requirements: {languageVersion=16, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}
   > Unable to download the toolchain. This may indicate that the combination (version, architecture, release/early access, ...) for the required JDK is not available.
      > Could not read 'https://api.adoptium.net/v3/binary/latest/16/ga/mac/aarch64/jdk/hotspot/normal/eclipse' because it does not exist.
```

I installed the arm-specific JDK and removed JDE

```
Matching Java virtual machines (2):
    19 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 19" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home
    17.0.4 (arm64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corrected 17" /Users/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corrected-17.0.4.1/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I can't figure out why I keep getting the error. I guess it's due to the arm architecture, but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If i run

```
cat `which java` | file -
```

i found out that actually i've 2 versions of Java:

```
/dev/stdin: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64eMach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
(null) (for architecture x86_64):
```

So i think this could be one of the cause of the problem.